# Shared Preferences for list

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

As a an inexperienced Android programmer I need some help. I'm designing this app for a church that needs an Activity that can record prayer requests (similar to making a to-do list). At this point I can type items into a list, but they don't seem to save and come back after closing using the Shared Preferences excerpt from below, also looking around this site it looks like I can do this without a physical button to press to save.

SharedPreferences prayerRequests = getPreferences(Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);

```
ListView myListViewa = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.myListView);

SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prayerRequests.edit();

editor.putString("prayers", myListViewa.toString());

editor.apply();
```

The entire class is here:

```
   package com.direction.investor.prayerjournal;

   import java.util.ArrayList;



   import android.annotation.TargetApi;
   import android.app.Activity;
   import android.os.Build;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.view.KeyEvent;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
   import android.widget.EditText;
   import android.widget.ListView;
   import android.widget.TextView;
   import android.content.SharedPreferences;
   import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;



 public class prayerRequests extends Activity {

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{ super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.prayerrequest);

ListView myListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.myListView);
final EditText myEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.myEditText);

final ArrayList<String> prayers = new ArrayList<String> ();

final ArrayAdapter<String> aa;

aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, prayers);

myListView.setAdapter(aa);



SharedPreferences prayerRequests = getPreferences(Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);

ListView myListViewa = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.myListView);

SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prayerRequests.edit();

editor.putString("prayers", myListViewa.toString());

editor.apply();






myEditText.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER) ||
                    (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {

                prayers.add(0, myEditText.getText().toString());
                aa.notifyDataSetChanged();
                myEditText.setText("");
                return true;

            }
        return false;
    }
});


}


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to use database instead of sharedpreferences

seee http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db